# Тормозят запросы к firebird

Tags: firebird

После некоторой работы с базой (select, insert, update, delete) база начинает сильно тормозить, и простой запрос выполняемый 3-5 мс, начинает выполнятся 3000-5000 мс. Помогает перезапуск firebird'а или backup/restore. Из-за чего такие тормоза? Как сделать так чтобы их не было, или хотя бы не на столько тормозили запросы.

К базе подключено 3 клиента, тормоза начинаются где то после 20000-50000 select'ов и порядка 10000 insert/delete/update

UPD:
gstat выдал это:

```
    Flags                   0
    Checksum                12345
    Generation              14835326
    Page size               4096
    ODS version             11.1
    Oldest transaction      13025843
    Oldest active           13025844
    Oldest snapshot         13025844
    Next transaction        14665107
    Bumped transaction      1
    Sequence number         0
    Next attachment ID      170157
    Implementation ID       24
    Shadow count            0
    Page buffers            0
    Next header page        0
    Database dialect        3
    Creation date           Jun 10, 2011 12:34:02
    Attributes              force write
```

Comment: Покажите статистику gstat по количеству открытых транзакций.

Comment: порядка 120 мб

Comment: Ну, разница между Oldest active и Next transaction достаточно большая.

Сначала сделайте свип вручную:

> gfix -sweep your_database

если сразу станет работать лучше, значит, в этом и проблема — много незакрытых транзакций, нужно потюнить сборку мусора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть нужно завершать транзакции. Возможно, вы открываете сеанс работы и выполняете все в одной транзакции, вот лог и распухает

Comment: Все сесии закрыты, а вот транзакции могут быть открыты и не закомичены (во время комита возникла ошибка) и rollback далеко не везде стоит. Тогда добавлю везде rollback. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Размер базы какой? Еще как вариант посмотреть размер страницы...
зы помотри сдесь может из-а того что classic он так выпендривается
http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ru/qsg15-classic-or-super-ru.html

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на тех характеристику файрберда. У многих такая же проблема. Решение - использовать более мощную.

Comment: Что более мощную? Другую базу?

Comment: Наверно, намекают на использование MySQL, Postgresql,  Oracle, mssql и тому подобное.

Comment: Хотел бы я чтобы была возможность поменять базу, но такой возможности нет.

Answer (score 0):

вот это

> порядка 10000 insert/delete/update

читать про версионность, сборку мусора и управление транзакциями на http://ibase.ru

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я понял, страница работает через аякс. Потому без перезагрузки у вас просто буфер firebird'а забивается и он не понимает, как и что с ним делать. Его используют, чтобы просто проследить ошибки и посылки, обычно хватает и 100 (это с головой просто хватает, чтобы понять, что работает, а что нет), так что не понимаю, зачем вы гоняете страницу, полностью с постоянно включенным firebird'ом.

Comment: вы наверное перепутали с firebug'ом. Я про базу firebird [http://www.firebirdsql.org/]

Comment: да. сори. чет я подустал уже. хватит на сегодня тут сидеть)))